# QSettings finds INI file but gives no result

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I tried to use QSettings and wrote a little test.

```
if(QFile("C:/Users/test/network.ini").exists()){
    QSettings settings("C:/Users/test/network.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.sync();
    settings.beginGroup("Network");
    settings.setValue("Port",9999);
    settings.endGroup();
    settings.sync();
    settings.beginGroup("Network");
    int port = settings.value("Port").toInt();
    settings.endGroup();
    settings.sync();
    qDebug() << port;
    return port;
}
```

My Ini file looks like that:

```
[Network]
Port=4444
```

The file path is correct but I still get no results.
Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

The error was caused by the qsettings.h in Qt 5.4.2

The orginal code was:

```
enum Format {
    IniFormat,
    IniFormat,

    InvalidFormat = 16,
    CustomFormat1,
    CustomFormat2,
    CustomFormat3,
    CustomFormat4,
    CustomFormat5,
    CustomFormat6,
    CustomFormat7,
    CustomFormat8,
    CustomFormat9,
    CustomFormat10,
    CustomFormat11,
    CustomFormat12,
    CustomFormat13,
    CustomFormat14,
    CustomFormat15,
    CustomFormat16
};
```

After I changed it to

```
enum Format {
    NativeFormat,
    IniFormat,

    InvalidFormat = 16,
    CustomFormat1,
    CustomFormat2,
    CustomFormat3,
    CustomFormat4,
    CustomFormat5,
    CustomFormat6,
    CustomFormat7,
    CustomFormat8,
    CustomFormat9,
    CustomFormat10,
    CustomFormat11,
    CustomFormat12,
    CustomFormat13,
    CustomFormat14,
    CustomFormat15,
    CustomFormat16
};
```

everything worked well.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but it doesn't seem right. The code you quoted wouldn't even compile.